# Configuração de seleção por cursor no visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao segurar o mouse e arrastar o vs code esta selecionando o texto como na imagem abaixo. Fazendo uma coluna de seleção, em vez do padrão que seria linha por linha selecionando todo o texto. Como faço para ele voltar para a configuração padrão?

Answer (score 1):

Acessar a barra de ferramentas, na parte superior da tela: "Selection" > desativar o "Column Selection Mode"